# In what ways can I mix jQuery and vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, web, frameworks

I have a web application, written in vanilla JavaScript.  I'd like to enhance it with jQuery animations and use a few features which I've found in various jQuery plugins, such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  In what ways is it possible to mix jQuery into vanilla JavaScript?  Will I need to use separate script tags or separate files?  Can I simply insert lines of code written with jQuery syntax into sections of plain JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Click here : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js, and think about what Barmar told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. jQuery is just a library of Javascript functions and methods -- it *is* ordinary Javascript.

Comment: So can I just throw a single line of jQuery inside a javascript loop?

Comment: Sure. It's just Javascript calling a function.