# Can I include JQuery on a page and mix jquery and std javascript in a separate included file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a simple problem that I am in search of a solution.  I have a JSP that includes jquery-1.10-2.  I have verified that it is pulling back the correct version in the Chrome console with $.fn.jquery.  I have a script tag in the jsp file that has some jquery functions in it, but I also have included a javascript file that has some regular javascript functions in it as well.

I've moved a jquery function into the included .js file, but I am now getting a '$ is not defined' error from Chrome.  Am I not able to mix standard javascript and jquery in one file?  For some reason it doesn't appear to be working.

I get this from within Chrome's console:
        *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*

amidst all of the POJS in the file, I have put in at the end:

```
$(function() {
    alert("HELLO!");
});
```

Simple enough of a test to run when the DOM is ready, yet nothing.  Can anyone chime in here and give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong?

I checked this SO question:  [In what ways can I mix jQuery and vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823215/in-what-ways-can-i-mix-jquery-and-vanilla-javascript)

From what I gleaned, it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes. Completely valid. jQuery is just a library written in vanilla js. The jQuery object itself is just a superset of the standard DOM objects. Try changing `$(function () { ...` to `jQuery(function () {...` to see if maybe the `$` global variable is being overwritten somewhere in your JavaScript before this is executed. If this works, something is overwriting your `$` global variable. If it doesn't work, jQuery is not defined prior to this snippet being run.

Comment: Has the `jquery` file been loaded by the time you try to access `$`?

Comment: Probably a mistake on the `script` tags order.

Comment: Yeah that's what it was... sometimes it's the stupid little things that trip me up... :: sigh :: thanks @brso05

Comment: @ResourceReaper no problem glad I could help!